# Video plays just the first 5 seconds

Tags: android, video, multimedia

Using:

```
private void play() {
    VideoView v = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.video);
    mp.setDisplay(v.getHolder());
    mp.start();
}
```

My video plays just about 5 first seconds, and stay like paused.. why does it happen? Is it something related to buffer? (I'm playing a local resource)

--

I've tried another 3gp video, and the same problem happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code (maybe was some problem with resource overuse):

```
private void play() throws Exception {
    v = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    if (!firstPlay) {
        mp.release();
    }
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.video);
    mp.setDisplay(v.getHolder());
    mp.start();
    firstPlay = false;
}
```

Comment: trying back the first code, it takes o little longer to stop, I really think is because of resource overuse on my many plays..

Answer (score 0):

Combining a `VideoView` and a `MediaPlayer` may not be the right approach. `VideoView` uses its own `MediaPlayer`. Either [use `VideoView` by itself](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Media/Video/), or [use a combination of `MediaPlayer` and `SurfaceView`](http://github.com/commonsguy/vidtry).

Comment: Also, video playback on an emulator does not tend to work well, unless you have a very fast PC.

Comment: Actually I have a very fast quad core here. By the way, how do I play the video using the MediaControler of your example?

Comment: @Tom Brito: To play the `VideoView` sample, tap on the top portion of the screen to bring up the `MediaController`, or add a call to `play()` towards the end of the setup process. To play the `MediaPlayer` example, you should get a URL field when you start up the app, to type in the path to a streaming video clip to test.

Comment: @Tom Brito: `play()` is on `VideoView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Are you sure? I'm not seeing it on the doc <http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html>

Comment: @Tom Brito: Sorry, on `VideoView` it is `start()`. I wish they would keep a consistent naming convention...

Comment: if I change my given answer from mp.start() to v.start() and mp.release() to v.stopPlayback() it does not work. By the way, the android developers page teach us to use the MediaPlayer in the way I did, not the VideoView directly. I wonder why, if the VideoView already have a MediaPlayer..